# Function app could not fetch message from Azure service bus

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have a service bus trigger function app, which could not fetch messages from a service bus topic. This happens only when the function app is put in VNET. Otherwise the function app could fetch the messages from service bus.

Below is the error message from logs.

```
Message processing error (Action=Receive, EntityPath={topicName}/Subscriptions/{SubscriptionName}, Endpoint={servicebus-namespace}01.servicebus.windows.net)Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ErrorCode: ConnectionReset (ServiceCommunicationProblem) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TransportStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)at
```

My Function app runs in an App service plan. My service bus runs as a Standard plan.

There is no change to the TLS settings of the function app. What are the other options to look into?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-service-endpoints#binding-service-bus-to-virtual-networks) and made the necessary configuration settings on your Service Bus end of it?

Comment: Azure Functions [guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options#virtual-network-triggers-non-http) for non-HTTP triggers - when your function app is in a VNet, you need to do necessary configuration on the Service bus resource as well.

Comment: My service bus runs in a standard plan, so I don't have the network options available. And I don't want to move to service bus premium plan.

Comment: I had created a Test function app in standard plan to test the behavior of Service bus triggered function app when placed in a VNET. It is able to pick messages from service bus. Not sure what is wrong with the other function app.

Answer (score 0):

This mostly occurs when function app and service bus resource are not on same VNET. Make sure that they are on same VNET.

As it is working perfectly in a normal function app, it should work as same after deploying it to VNET, if not, we need to whitelist the IP or CIDR at service bus level.

- We can find the function IP under functionapp.

Here if we use function app as premium tier, then there is no need of whitelisting.

Check these [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-service-endpoints#use-azure-portal) for allowing access for specific virtual network, also check this [answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/497721/azure-function-to-be-triggered-by-service-bus-whic.html) which is similar to resolve your issue. thanks to MayankBargali.